# Table containing foreign keys only

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

Can a table contain only foreign keys and from other table's attribute, or those foreign keys will be mark as table's primary key.

Comment: Your diagram appears to be missing some lines, btw

Comment: I'd relate stuff on customer_id rather than email. I know email is unique but what do you do if a user wants to change their registered email? Update all their past auctions too?

Answer (score 1):

A primary key serves to uniquely identify a row, and is helpful for locationg existing data for update/delete purposes, or when other data refers to it

Data that only refers to something else can certainly have foreign keys but no primary keys; think about a log -  row - "customer X viewed product Y at time Z" - it might only ever refer to other data but have no need to be referred to uniquely in and of itself; those entries are written, and maybe analyzed later in aggregate but there isn't a need to change anything about them or prevent "duplications" (if you only log to a minute precision, the customer might view the same product several times in the minute - interesting in itself, and you don't care about the apparent duplication)

Bid is something like a log table, if bids cannot be deleted or updated (I assume the user makes another bid entry if they want  to pay more?) so it would appear to be OK for it not to have a primary key

Comment: I forgot to mention that one person can only create one Bid and update the Bid amount.

Comment: @Programforlifeitf then email, auction id and product id in combination are your PK. Considering that Auction id determines the product, you can leave product id completely out of the picture.

Comment: I think Shadow means that email+auctionid are the PK... Seems Bid doesn't need a productid at all. While we're insepcting the rest of the schema, does an audtion have an email because it's owned by a customer? I've always preffered to put the reason into the column name in such a case; Email should be called CustomerId, and the column in Auction should be called e.g. Seller_CustomerID whereas in Bid it should be called Bidder_CustomerID

Comment: Yes, an Auction is owned by a customer who placed them. I removed the Product table as it isn't necessary to have one. And I have rename some attributes based on Caius Jard's suggestion for better referring.